# Comparing SQL dates in SQL Standard format. Does it work always?

Tags: sql, sqlite, date, datetime, time

I was looking for some answers on comparing dates in SQLite, and some answers pointed that as long as your date format is in:

YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS (assuming HH:MM:SS is in 24-hour format)

you'll be ALWAYS fine if you compare them as strings (either comparing one date against other, or checking if a date is between 2 dates). Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 'YYYY-MM-DD' BETWEEN 'YYYY-MM-DD' AND 'YYYY-MM-DD'
```

One thing I noticed for this format is that it starts with the highest possible "range", year, followed by month, etc. I'm trying to grasp on whether this will work always (algos are not my strong side), so my question is, are there any "edge" cases against which this will NOT work?

Comment: Telling whether the field is equal to a date (the date being in the same string format) or between two dates (of the same format) would work but because the field is not actually a date you would prohibit yourself from being able to use date and time functions without converting the field to a date every time you use the field in a query. You would have to use `substr` with the correct position of every component of interest, as opposed to using functions designed for that purpose. Why do you not want to just define the field as what it is (a date)?

Comment: @BrianDeMilia: SQLite does not have a `date` data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work as long as your dates are between Jan 1, 0 and Dec 31, 9999.  This is sufficient for most applications, but not quite "always".

SQLite prepends years before 1000 with zeros.  If it did not, the range would actually be from Jan 1, 1000.

Comment: @CL. . . . I updated the answer.  However, when originally answering, I really didn't think that years between 0 and 999 were particularly relevant.  They don't change the gist of the answer, which is "in all practical cases" but not "always".